# pytorch DCGAN tutorial - why tanh as a last activation instead of sigmoid?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm reading through the [PyTorch DCGAN tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) and the last activation of the generator is `tanh`. Later on in the tutorial, [`make_grid`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.utils.make_grid.html#torchvision.utils.make_grid) is called with `normalize=True` to bring the values to the 0-1 range. I was wondering if there was a reason to use `tanh` instead of `sigmoid` for the final activation, as `sigmoid` would bring the values to the 0-1 range and would obviate the need for the normalization. Is it a question of taste, or does `tanh` improve something about the model? Thanks!